# How to enter a data in android studio to firebase using PHP

Tags: java, php, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I know how to insert data from editText in android studio to a database in firebase using

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
```

well this way it is easier but my lecturer wants to make life harder and asks me to insert data from the editexts using PHP and send them to the database, is this possible? how can it be done?

Comment: Did you try anything already? There are quite a few promising results here: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+enter+a+data+to+firebase+using+PHP

Comment: yep ive obviously googled it but i couldnt find any android implementation

Comment: Can you explain (in your question) how you intend to combine Android and PHP here?